# Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException SSL connection timeout in facebook api 3.0.0 in base.facebook.php

Tags: facebook

i am getting same ssl error  for all version of php-sdk i have increased timeout value but strill same problem but when i tried same sample code on different server it working well. i think there is might be something server related issue like version of lib curl or openssl can you help me ?

Comment: try this post : [Link](http://facebookegyapi.blogspot.com/2011/09/fatal-error-uncaught-curlexception-ssl.html)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue two weeks ago with two computers running on Archlinux with curl 7.24.

Curl use SSL version 3 by default but it looks like on my computers the curl to https://graph.facebook.com ended up in a timeout whereas it worked when I specifically asked curl to use SSL version 3. So here how I solved the issue :

In the Facebook PHP SDK, in base_facebook.php, replace :

```
public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'facebook-php-3.1',
);
```

By :

```
public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'facebook-php-3.1',
  CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 3,
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!!  1 week trying to solving this!!! Your fix solved my problem too! CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 3,