# PHP Shopify Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ShopifyClientCurlException' with message 'SSL connection timeout'

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate, shopify

Just starting out with shopfiy and this is my first ever stack post!

I'm trying to setup Sandeeps Shetty's "Simple Shopify API client in PHP" found here:

https://github.com/sandeepshetty/shopify_client

I keep seeing the following error in my logs (i've removed full paths and api creds):

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ShopifyClientCurlException' with
>   message 'SSL connection timeout' in
>   shopify_client/shopify_client.php:67\nStack trace:\n#0
>   shopwriters/shopify_client/shopify_client.php(36): shopify_api('POST',
>   'https://baumbac...', NULL, Array)\n#1
>   /home/matt/public_html/projects/shopwriters/public_html/index.php(20):
>   oauth_access_token('shopurl...', 'xxx...', 'xxx...', 'xxx...')\n#2
>   {main}\n  thrown in shopify_client/shopify_client.php on line 67

Anyone had a similar issue? I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: That's an SSL issue. Can you access the SSL URL manually (in your browser)?

Comment: Well the main thing you want to re-search is the 'SSL Connection Timeout'. Take a look at http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/php-curl-ssl-connection-timeout/ But I'm afraid I cannot provide much more help as I've never worked with the Shopify API or even heard of such. Sorry and good luck.

Comment: Hey thanks for your input - currently researching now.

Comment: I'll tell you what, I'll add a bounty to the question tomorrow. That should rake up the answers. I can't do it today as the question must be two days old.

Comment: that sounds awesome, if I find the fix I'll post

Comment: @Matt you might also want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511802/fatal-error-uncaught-curlexception-ssl-connection-timeout-in-facebook-api-3-0-0

Comment: @EdwardOcampo-Gooding - I added CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 3 and it now works! :)

Comment: Brilliant. You should add that as an answer and accept it (in case anyone else has the same issue and misses your comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix for this problem was adding:

CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 3

to wcurl.php in the $default_curl_opts array.

Thanks to all who helped out!